# Pytorch RNN works badly when training sequentially through the whole dataset but works well when training on random selected training examples

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, training-data

I'm working on a toy RNN example on PyTorch published on the official website [NLP FROM SCRATCH: CLASSIFYING NAMES WITH A CHARACTER-LEVEL RNN](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html) and I want to rewrite code based on my own understanding on PyTorch. Following the tutorial, I successfully read the text data (you can download it [here](https://download.pytorch.org/tutorial/data.zip)) and split it into a training dataset (80%) and a test dataset (20%). I also defined the RNN model and designed the whole training and testing process. But when it goes to the training process, I found that the model could be trained normally on randomly selected training examples and perform well on the test dataset, however, when the model was trained sequentially through the whole training dataset, its performance was really bad both on training and test dataset. My PyTorch version is pytorch_1.12.1 with CUDA GPU support installed by conda. Here I post my python code.

```py
# %% [markdown]
# ### Import Utils for Processing Text Data

# %%
import os
import glob
import unicodedata
import string

from typing import List, Tuple, Dict


# %% [markdown]
# ### Function to Find Dataset Files

# %%
def get_data_files(path_pattern: str) -> List:
    return glob.glob(path_pattern)


print(get_data_files('data/nlp_from_scratch/names/*.txt'))


# %% [markdown]
# ### Function to Turn a Unicode to ASCII

# %%
def get_letters_ASCII() -> str:
    return string.ascii_letters+" .,;'"


def unicode_to_ASCII(s: str) -> str:
    letters_ASCII = get_letters_ASCII()
    return "".join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize("NFD", s) if unicodedata.category(c) != "Mn" and c in letters_ASCII)


print(unicode_to_ASCII('Ślusàrski'))


# %% [markdown]
# ### Function to Read Dataset

# %%
def read_dataset(data_files: List) -> Tuple[List, Dict]:
    categories = []
    name_dict = {}
    for file in data_files:
        category = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
        categories.append(category)
        lines = open(file).read().strip().split("\n")
        name_dict[category] = lines
    return categories, name_dict


print(read_dataset(get_data_files('data/nlp_from_scratch/names/*.txt')))


# %% [markdown]
# ### Turning Names into Tensors
# 
# Now that we have all the names organized, we need to turn them into
# Tensors to make any use of them.
# 
# To represent a single letter, we use a "one-hot vector" of size
# ``<1 x n_letters>``. A one-hot vector is filled with 0s except for a 1
# at index of the current letter, e.g. ``"b" = <0 1 0 0 0 ...>``.
# 
# To make a word we join a bunch of those into a 2D matrix
# ``<line_length x 1 x n_letters>``.
# 
# That extra 1 dimension is because PyTorch assumes everything is in
# batches - we're just using a batch size of 1 here.
# 
# 
# 

# %% [markdown]
# ### Import Data

# %%
categories,name_dict=read_dataset(get_data_files('data/nlp_from_scratch/names/*.txt'))

# %% [markdown]
# ### Prepare Dataset

# %%
import random


def get_train_test_data(categories: List, name_dict: Dict):
    train_data = []
    test_data = []
    for i in range(len(categories)):
        name_list = name_dict[categories[i]]
        random.shuffle(name_list)
        num_samples = len(name_list)
        label = i
        for j in range(num_samples):
            if j < int(0.8*num_samples):
                train_data.append((name_list[j], label))
            else:
                test_data.append((name_list[j], label))
    return train_data, test_data


train_data, test_data = get_train_test_data(categories,name_dict)
print("Number of training data")
print(len(train_data))
print("Number of testing data")
print(len(test_data))


# %%
import torch

def word_to_tensor(w:str)->torch.Tensor:
    letters_ASCII=get_letters_ASCII()
    n_letters=len(letters_ASCII)
    one_hot=torch.zeros(len(w),1,n_letters)
    for i,c in enumerate(w):
        letter_index=letters_ASCII.find(c)
        one_hot[i][0][letter_index]=1
    return one_hot

print("Word to tensor example")
print(word_to_tensor("andrew").shape)
print(word_to_tensor("andrew"))
    

# %%
import random
def get_random_sample(data:List[Tuple]):
    sample=data[random.randint(0,len(data)-1)]
    return sample

# %% [markdown]
# ## Creating the Network
# ![rnn](https://i.imgur.com/Z2xbySO.png)

# %%
import torch.nn as nn

# I use nn.CrossEntropyLoss so the softmaxlayer is not implemented
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.i2o = nn.Linear(input_size+hidden_size, output_size)
        self.i2h = nn.Linear(input_size+hidden_size, hidden_size)

    def init_hidden(self):
        return torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size)

    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        combined = torch.cat((input, hidden),1)
        hidden = self.i2h(combined)
        output = self.i2o(combined)
        return output, hidden


model = RNN(len(get_letters_ASCII()), 128, len(categories))


# %%
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.005)


# %%
def train_one_epoch(train_data:List[Tuple], model:RNN, loss_fn: nn.CrossEntropyLoss, optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer, device: str):
    model.train()
    avg_loss = 0.0
    num_samples = len(train_data)
    
    for i in range(num_samples): 
        sample=get_random_sample(train_data) # Works well
        # sample=train_data[i] # Works badly when iterate though whole dataset
        x,y=sample
        x=word_to_tensor(x)
        y=torch.tensor([y])
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        hidden = model.init_hidden().to(device)
        output=torch.zeros(1,len(categories))
        for j in range(x.size()[0]):
            output, hidden = model(x[j], hidden)
        loss = loss_fn(output, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        avg_loss += loss.item()/num_samples
    return avg_loss


# %%
# loss=train_one_epoch(train_dataset,model,loss_fn,optimizer,"cpu")
# print(loss)

# %%
def test(test_data:List[Tuple],model:RNN,device:str):
    model.eval()
    num_correct=0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i in range(len(test_data)):
            x,y=test_data[i]
            x=word_to_tensor(x).to(device)
            y=torch.tensor([y])
            hidden = model.init_hidden().to(device)
            output=torch.zeros(1,len(categories))
            for j in range(x.size()[0]):
                output, hidden = model(x[j], hidden)
            num_correct+=(torch.argmax(output)==y).type(torch.float).sum().item()
    return num_correct

# %%
def run_train(num_epoches: int, train_data: List[Tuple], test_data: List[Tuple], model: RNN, loss_fn: nn.CrossEntropyLoss, optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer, device: str):
    model.to(device)
    for epoch in range(num_epoches):
        loss = train_one_epoch(train_data, model, loss_fn, optimizer, device)
        num_correct_train = test(train_data, model, device)
        num_correct_test = test(test_data, model, device)
        print("epoch %d, loss %f, train: correct %d all train %d train accuracy %f, test: correct %d all test %d test accuracy %f" % (
            epoch, loss, num_correct_train, len(train_data), num_correct_train/len(train_data), num_correct_test, len(test_data), num_correct_test/len(test_data)))


# %%
run_train(1, train_data, test_data, model, loss_fn, optimizer, "cpu")
```

The problem is at about lines 176-177, in function `train_one_epoch` where the code is `sample=...`. The code aims to fetch training examples in the training dataset. The training dataset is organized as `List[Tuple[str,int]]`, where a training example is a tuple with a name string and a class label, and the training dataset is a list of these tuples. One version is to fetch training examples randomly (works well) and the other is fetch training examples sequentially (works badly). I am not sure if there are any silly mistakes in basic python grammar in my code (but it runs) and I can not figure out the cause of the differences. Thanks for your help.

I tried to print the grad of parameters during training, the random fetch version seemed good but the sequential fetch seemed weird, but I don't know why it happened.

Comment: With a random sampling, it is pretty much guaranteed that you see the same datapoint at least twice per epoch. That will definitely affect your epoch metrics, if that is what you are using to gauge whether it works or not. In any case, consider updating your question to explain how you measure success.

Comment: The code is runnable if you just download the dataset and correctly extract it. The code will output the train accuracy and test accuracy after 1 epoch training. For correctly runned result (random samping) both the accuracy are about 0.6, for badly runned result (iterating through the whole dataset)  both the accuracy is below 0.05 and the training process is incorrect. My problem is I cannot figure out why it cannnot work through iteraing through the whole dataset. If you uncomment line 177 and comment line 176 and run the code again you will see the problem.

Comment: In that case, do consider that you are evaluating different amounts of iterations over your data, and that definitely you are comparing unequal datasets. Of course that is not all of the problem, but it needs to be taken care of.